# How can I create a fetch url with optional input fields within a web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, fetch

I am making an API call by using fetch method(GET) of Jquery. My question is, how can include empty input fields **(totally  optional, user may fill those areas, maybe not)** into my fetch url. When I tried to send them as empty string, server is responding with a status code(400)- bad request.

**These are the optional input fields to fill**
[image]

**MY JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
var fetchUrl = "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode="
+iataOrigin+"&destinationLocationCode="
+iataDestination+"&departureDate="
+getFlightDepartureDate()+"&adults="
+getFlightAdults()+"&max="+getmaxTicket()

console.log(fetchUrl)

const settings = {
    "url": fetchUrl,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        
            "Authorization" : "Bearer myTokenInHere"

    }
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

For instance, I want to declare a URL such as 'adult number input field value' is not initialized, it's an empty string. Like this :

> "&adults="

After trying this, server is not responding with a status code 200. I would be very thankful for your help.

Comment: What URL are you creating? You seem to be on the right track, so it is just some weird typo or unexpected value. Or, there is nothing wrong with your code and the API you're using just doesn't allow it to be blank. The API may require it to be omitted instead or something. Each API is a little different and you'll have to look at that specific API.

Comment: @samanime As I understand it from API, it says : " if an input field will be blank, then do not include it in your URL". However, I do not want to deal with if statements to control wheter the input fields are blank are not. That's kinda hard to code

Comment: Well, if your API says that, you have to omit it like they say. You don't have a choice there. For each part, just do an if and concat on each piece if it isn't blank, or skip it if it is. Doesn't sound like their API gives you an option.